# FabricJs load previous/current step without using canvas.toJSON()

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am using FabricJs to create an online image editor.

Is a simple thing, this actions: zoom, rotate, flipX, undo, redo.

I firstly tried to use the toJSON, and fromJSON, but I saw that when the user was clicking on the undo button fabricjs reloads the image, and also the configuration object that returns the `canvas.toJSON()` is pretty big and i want to store all the steps in a database.

I tried to create my own configuration object, storing only this properties:

```
    {
        filters: FabricFilter[];
        rotation: number;
        flipX: boolean;
        position: {
            top: number,
            left: number
        };
        zoom: number;
    }
```

The single mouse event is when the user move/fit the image in the canvas, all other actions are made programatically.

The problem I have is that when the user rotates an image, and then tries to apply a filter, 
the rotation is lost, or the image is out of the canvas.

I place here some code here:

```
    setConfig(canvasEl, imageEl, config) {
        if (config.hasOwnProperty('zoom')) {
            canvasEl.setZoom(config.zoom);
        }
        if (config.hasOwnProperty('flipX')) {
            imageEl.flipX = config.flipX;
        }
        if (config.hasOwnProperty('position')) {
            imageEl.top = position.top;
            imageEl.left = position.left;
        }
        if (config.hasOwnProperty('rotation')) {
            imageEl.angle = rotation;
        }
        if (config.hasOwnProperty('filters')) {
            imageEl.filters = config.filters;
            imageEl.applyFilters();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to store the configuration of a
fabric canvas(the same as toJSON, loadFromJSON,
but with less properties), and then to update the canvas object, depending on the stored configuration.

Any help will be really appreciated.
Maybe I didn't explain very good my problem, so if any of you don't understand something, I'll be more than happy to answer your questions, and edit the post.

Thank you